# roslaunch: is neither a launch file in package

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-kinetic, nao, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using *Kinetic* and I'm trying to launch `other's and examples codes` but all *roslaunch* shows this message:

```
[*.launch] is neither a launch file in package [nao_description] nor is [nao_description] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I used `source /home/myuser/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` and roslaunch again, but the problem still.
Someone can help please...?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360352/roslaunch:-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package/) by [synapsido](https://answers.ros.org/users/20161/synapsido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2020-08-25**:
I get that error when I try roslaunch in the wrong folder, or misspell the file name.

If you're not in the folder of the launch file, you have to use the exact path in the call. Try it first from within the folder containing the launch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Things to check

- Is the package compiled with `catkin_make` or `catkin build` and was that successful?
- Can you find it in `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`
- Can you find it in `rospack list | grep <package name>`

---

Originally posted by [Loy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1830/loy/) with karma: 141 on 2021-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dvogureckiy99](https://answers.ros.org/users/101502/dvogureckiy99/) on 2023-02-18**:
if I can't find package, but catkin build went well, what can be the problem ? (but maybe I runed `catkin build` in different package).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I had a typo: instead of package.launch I named the file package_launch. After renaming it worked  :-)